# echo Spitting Out Extra Characters

Tags: php, wordpress, urlencode, str-replace, var-dump

Here's what's going on and the results of each (desired behavior):

```
echo urlencode('q&a'); // q%26a
echo str_replace('&', '%26', 'q%26a');
```

But when I try this with wordpress it breaks:

`$title = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', get_the_title()));`

```
echo urlencode($title); // q%26%23038%3Ba
echo str_replace('&', '%26', $title); // q%26#038;a
```

If I echo just the title it's `q&a` but this ends up in the querystring so I'm trying to escape the ampersand. Anyone know what's going on / how to fix this?

## EDIT

I recently noticed that a `var_dump` of `$title` spits out `string(8) "q&a"` which doesn't make sense as `q&a` is only 3 characters. Does that help any further?

Comment: The idea of `urlencode()` is that you can safely put the result directly into a URL - I don't see why `str_replace()` is being used...

Comment: I get what you're saying and it's quite valid. I just wanted to show more than one example. I tried `strtr` as well. What I will end up using is `urlencode` of course.

Comment: Where's the actual problem - which function? `#038;` looks like an XML entity reference to me...

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton It's correct yes, but the ampersand is being encoded/replaced twice. I would think wordpress' `get_the_title()` has something to do with it. I just tested and found that a `var_dump` of $title is `string(8) "q&a"` which doesn't seem right.. 8 characters for "q&a"? Something is definitely amiss..